# How to make element resizable, in xul?

Tags: css, firefox, dom, firefox-addon, xul

I'm trying to add resize ability to the network panel of Firefox devtools. I used DOM inspector to add a `<resizer>` element after the top label element, then set `element=request-menu-file-header-box` [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/resizer) using the DOM Node inspector, but it doesn't let me resize the column:

[image: Resizer to the right of file column]

I tried fiddling with the width of the columns, thinking it wouldn't resize because of set width, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Is there a way to make these elements resizable?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a [`<splitter>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/splitter). Using the following after the `request-menu-file-header-box` element seems to work for me (Nightly on OSX)

```
<splitter resizebefore="closest" resizeafter="closest"/>
```